# Gammu and PostgreSQL send 8bit sms

Tags: postgresql, binary, message, 8-bit, gammu

I'm working with Gammu and PostgreSQL to send sms from my computer.
I have success sending a normal text sms.

But i have some problem now when trying to send 8bit (Binary) message to my devices. Here's my simple query to inject message to gammu 'outbox' table.

```
INSERT INTO outbox (
"DestinationNumber",
"Text",
"TextDecoded",
"Coding",
"UDH",
"CreatorID") VALUES (
'202555xxxx',
'02616A03776C66JF010000198C000403E800013003F200013003F30002323003F400023230',
'',
'8bit',
'06050407d50000',
'ConfigurationSMS');
```

as you can see `02616A03776C66JF010000198C000403E800013003F200013003F30002323003F400023230` is my SMS text encoded using hex values. The value is correct while in outbox table.

But when the message has been sent and i'm look on my inbox table, the Text value change to this `02616A03776C66BF0100000D8C000203E800013103F2000131FD00 00007400650073007400`

Does anyone know why Gammu send different text? and how to prevent the changes occur? Thanks.

Comment: Your string is NOT "hex" encoded since it contains a "J" char.

Comment: ah, right. it's my fault while encoding my text. now my code work perfectly. !! Thanks !! @A.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, there is invalid char in the HEX encoded string.

But I think Gammu should complain on such error, so I'll work on fixing that upstream, see https://github.com/gammu/gammu/issues/185 for progress.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thank you very much.  @michal